# how can I cache in public proxy the heavy image I use for my header (using background-image:url css property in the stylesheet)

Tags: css, caching, proxy, background-image

ok this is the image.

it is certainly too big and needs cropping but it's not the point right now:
http://exaggerated.com/images/site/front/header.png

in my stylesheet I use

```
#wrapper_inner {
width:100%;
height:auto;
float:left;
background-image:url(http://exaggerated.com/images/site/front/header.png);
background-position:top center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

my question is could I put the image on a public proxy and use the new external url to serve this ressource faster for first time visitors ?

Comment: What do you mean by "public proxy"? A Content Delivery Network (CDN)? That will cost money

Answer (score 0):

You should set HTTP headers that allow for caching, and then the user's proxy (if any) will cache the image for you. http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf